# In Laravel how to manage nested auth system?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-authentication, laravel-permission

I want to create architecture as the follow tree.

- Super-Admin

  - Managers
  - Editors
  - Admins
  - View-Only
  - Vendors (Can create Vendors profiles)

Super-Admin and Admin also can Create Vendors (Vendors table must be separate)

Vendors can also directly Signup/Signin
Each Vendor have their own users backend users and frontend users.

- Backend

  - Vendor

    - Managers
    - Editors
    - Admins
    - View-Only
    - Frontend Users (create frontend users profile)
- Frontend Users

Front-end Users can also signup directly from frontend / social-login also allowed

Please help me how i will manage user Auth for this kind of architecture in Laravel?
I want front-end users table separate, vendors table separate and super-admins table separate. just to reduce data length in each table and easy to manage.

I don't know how i will make base structure for this, how group permissions will work with this complex structure.

Want to use laravel-7+

Answer (score 0):

First look into RBAC (role based access control) to see how it is to have an idea.

Laravel authentication has [guards](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#closure-request-guards) that you can use to authenticate different users from different tables. Just define different guards for each of your tables and use them wherever you want.

Also look at [authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization). You can define different gates and policies for different user types to check their role and allow/deny them.